# using `proportionBF` to carry out one-sample proportion test (more than two levels)

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian

I want to compute Bayes Factor for one-sample proportion test where the null hypothesis is that-

> The proportions for the levels for the nominal variable are not
>   different from the theoretical proportions

I know how to use `proportionBF` from `BayesFactor` package to do this when there are two proportions with the null hypothesis being that the two levels are equally likely (`p = 0.5`). This is equivalent to `stats::binom.test`.

```r
# frequentist test (p-value > 0.05)
broom::tidy(stats::binom.test(x = 21, n = 44, p = 0.5))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>   estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1    0.477        21   0.880        44    0.325     0.633 Exact~
#> # ... with 1 more variable: alternative <chr>

# quantifying evidence in favor of null hypothesis
library(BayesFactor)
1/ proportionBF(y = 21, N = 44, p = 0.5, rscale = 0.707)

#> Bayes factor analysis
#> --------------
#> [1] Null, p=0.5 : 3.724132 ±0.02%
#> 
#> Against denominator:
#>   Alternative, p0 = 0.5, r = 0.707, p =/= p0 
#> ---
#> Bayes factor type: BFproportion, logistic
```

But I don't know how to do this analysis when there are more than two proportions, the equivalent of `stats::chisq.test` (a goodness of fit test).

```r
# frequentist test (p-value > 0.05)
table(mtcars$cyl)
#> 
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14
broom::tidy(stats::chisq.test(x = table(mtcars$cyl)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   statistic p.value parameter method                                  
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                   
#> 1      2.31   0.315         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
```

How can I compute Bayes Factor for this test using `BayesFactor` package?

(P.S. If not possible, I'd also be interested in knowing any other package that can do the same.)

Comment: Did you try [contingencyTableBF](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BayesFactor/versions/0.9.12-4.2/topics/contingencyTableBF)? (see also the [BayesFactor manual](https://richarddmorey.github.io/BayesFactor/#ctables) on this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of `BayesFactor` answered this question here:
https://gist.github.com/richarddmorey/a4cd3a2051f373db917550d67131dba4